# How do I get to node 25 and 50 in my binary tree? I have to get a preorder of the binary tree in output

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

```
//
// BinTree class
//
// this class implements a binary tree
//
// the tree is unbounded. fields are
//     info: the value stored in the node (generic type)
//     left:   pointer to the left subtree
//     right:  pointer to the right subtree
//     parent: pointer to the parent
//     preOrderQueue: queue of nodes for preorder traversal
//                    left, right, and parent are public to allow the client                                           //                        code to manipulate the tree as needed
//
// methods:
//     constructor to create empty tree
//     constructor to create tree with one node
//     constructor to create tree given the root value, and
//          pointers to the left and right subtrees
//     get and set methods for the info field
//     isEmpty 
//     attachLeft:  if there is no left child, attach the given tree as
//                  the new left child; otherwisethrowTreeViolationException
//     attachRight: if there is no right child, attach the given tree as the          //                      new right child; otherwise throw TreeViolationException
//     detachLeft:  detach and return the left child
//     detachRight: detach and return the right child
//     root:        return the root of the tree

public class BinTree<T> implements BinTreeInterface<T> {

    protected T info;
    public BinTree<T> left;
    public BinTree<T> right;
    public BinTree<T> parent;
    private LinkedUnbndQueue<T> preOrderQueue;

// create an empty tree
    public BinTree() {
        info = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        parent = null;
    }

// create a tree with one node
    public BinTree(T item) {

    info = item;
    right = null;   //idk
    left = null;   //idk
    }

// create a tree where the root contains item
// link the left and right subtrees to the root
// don't forget to set the parent pointers
    public BinTree(T item, BinTree<T> ltree, BinTree<T> rtree) {

          info = item;
          right = rtree;
          left = ltree;

          ltree = null;
          rtree = null;

    }

// return the info field
    public T getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

// set the info field
    public void setInfo(T newitem) {
        info = newitem;
    }

// attach the parm as the left child of the current node
// throw TreeViolationException if the current node already has a left child
    public void attachLeft(BinTree<T> tree) {

        if (this.left != null)
        throw new TreeViolationException("Current node already has a left              child");

        else
             this.left = tree;
}

// attach the parm as the right child of the current node
// throw TreeViolationException if the current node already has a right child
    public void attachRight(BinTree<T> tree) {

            if (this.right != null)
                throw new TreeViolationException("Current node already has a   right child");

                else
                     this.right = tree;
    }

// detach the left child and return it
     public BinTree<T> detachLeft() {

           return this.left;
    }

// detach the right child and return it
    public BinTree<T> detachRight() {

        return this.right;

    }
```

I think my BinTree method is wrong. I dont understand where I am making mistake.

```
public BinTree<T> root() {

     if (this.parent == null)
         return this;

     else
         return this.root();
        /// return parent;

         }
// Initializes preOrderQueue with tree elements in preOrder order.
    public void preOrder(BinTree<T> tree)  {
        if (tree != null) {
            preOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
            preOrder(tree.left);
            preOrder(tree.right);
        }
    }

// calls preorder to create queue of nodes in the tree
    public void reset()  {
      preOrderQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<T>();
      preOrder(this);
    }

// removes and returns the next node in the preorder queue
// returns null if the queue is empty
    public T getNext()  {
        if (preOrderQueue.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return preOrderQueue.dequeue();
     }

 }
```

Here is my driver code.
// When I compile fr preorder it only prints out 75 and below bcz at tht time the current node is 75. why is it not traversing 25 and 50?

```
public class useTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num;
        BinTree<Integer> mytree = new BinTree<Integer>(25);
        BinTree<Integer> subtree = new BinTree<Integer>(50);
        mytree.attachLeft(subtree);
        subtree = new BinTree<Integer>(75);
        mytree.attachRight(subtree);

        // subtree = new BinTree<Integer>(10);
        // mytree.attachRight(subtree);
        //         25
        //       /    \
        //     50      75


        subtree = new BinTree<Integer>(10);
        subtree.attachRight(new BinTree<Integer>(100));
        subtree.attachLeft(new BinTree<Integer>(200));
        mytree = mytree.right;
        mytree.attachLeft(subtree);

        //         25
        //       /    \
        //     50      75
        //            /
        //           10
        //          /  \
        //        200  100

        mytree = mytree.root();
        System.out.println("\npreorder traversal:");
        mytree.reset();
        num = mytree.getNext();
        while (num != null) {
        System.out.println(num);
        num = mytree.getNext();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public BinTree root() {

 if (this.parent == null)
     return this;

 else
     return this.root();
    /// return parent;

     }
```

Should be:

```
 public BinTree root() {
     if (this.parent == null)
         return this;
     else
         return this.parent.root();
 }
```

This uses recursion, which is less than optimal, but it is at least correct.

Also:

```
private LinkedUnbndQueue<T> preOrderQueue;
```

Each *node* of the tree has its own queue? That's not right. If you really want to generate a queue, pass the queue object to the relevant method. And, why does the `preOrder` method need a tree argument - it's not a static method; "this" serves as an implicit argument.

```
public void preOrder(LinkedUnbndQueue<T> preOrderQueue)  {
    preOrderQueue.enqueue(this.getInfo());
    if (left != null) left.preOrder(preOrderQueue);
    if (right != null) right.preOrder(preOrderQueue);
}
```

Also, `attachLeft` and `attachRight` methods needs to set the `parent` field of the attached subtree.

More generally, your `BinTree` is both a node and a tree. That can work but some operations don't really make sense on a per-node basis (in particular the custom iteration that you have defined should be moved out, since as I noted, it doesn't make much sense to have a queue per node).

Frankly, there are enough problems with this code that you need a better approach to your development practice. Consider learning to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
public BinTree root() {
    if (parent == null) return null;

    BinTree tmp = parent;
    while (tmp.parent != null) {
        tmp = tmp.parent;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

You should create a separate class naming `BinNode` or something. Tree and Node are separate things and the class you created is confusing and doesn't make sense.

**Also**, you are not assigning the `parent` variable anywhere.

```
public void attachRight(BinTree<T> tree) {

    if (this.right != null)
        throw new TreeViolationException("Current node already has a   right child");

    else {
        this.right = tree;
        tree.parent = this;
    }
}
```

Assign the parent of the child branches appropriately. Moreover, your detach methods are wrong too. You are simply returning the right/left branches but you are supposed to **detach**/**remove** them first.

```
BinTree branch = this.right; // or left
this.right = null;
return branch;
```